# Как передать данные между фрагментами ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Написал код в котором есть StepperIndicator и ViewPager,теперь пришло время работы с фрагментами передавать значения между ними,ну например в первом фрагменте ввел имя ,а в втором это имя я должен получить и вывести.Как мне это сделать,я еще не опытен в этой теме,знаю что передавать с фрагмента в фрагмент на прямую не совсем правильно,через Activity не знаю как делать именно в моем примере.Поэтому я решил сделать через `newInstance`.Подскажите как это сделать,за ранее спасибо.

> Главная Активити

```
public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        final ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        assert pager != null;
        PagerAdapterIndicator adapter = new PagerAdapterIndicator(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final StepperIndicator indicator =findViewById(R.id.stepper_indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager, true);
        indicator.addOnStepClickListener(new StepperIndicator.OnStepClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStepClicked(int step) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(step, true);
            }
        });

    } }
```

> Adapter

```
    public class PagerAdapterIndicator extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

       public PagerAdapterIndicator(FragmentManager fm) {
           super(fm);
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return 5;
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position)
           {
               case 0:
                   return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1, position == getCount() - 1);

               case 1:
                   return  PageFragment2.newInstance(position + 1, position == getCount() - 1);

               case 2:
                   return  PageFragment3.newInstance(position + 1, position == getCount() - 1);

               case 3:


         return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1, position == getCount() - 1);

           case 4:
               return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1, position == getCount() - 1);

       }
       return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1, position == getCount() - 1);
   }
}
```

> Fragment2

```
public class PageFragment2 extends Fragment {

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page, boolean isLast) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page", page);
        if (isLast)
            args.putBoolean("isLast", true);
        final PageFragment2 fragment2 = new PageFragment2();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment2;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

> Fragment1

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page, boolean isLast) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page", page);
        if (isLast)
            args.putBoolean("isLast", true);
        final PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Заголовок должен содержать краткую суть проблемы

Comment: @pavlofff как передать значение с 1 фрагмента  во второй ,с помощью newInstance ?  или если знает лучше способ то напишите .

Comment: смотрите по запросу passing data between fragments viewpager

Comment: Как я понимаю, тут не ViewPager нужен, а некий способ реализовать так называемый Fragment Flow, случай, когда в одной базовой активити стек фрагментов отвечает за один процесс (например регистрацию). В таком случае данные надо хранить вовсе не внутри фрагментов, а в какой то базовой сущности, которая имеет доступ ко всем фрагментам, например это может быть некий презентер (как абстракция). Почитайте про паттерн mvp и посмотрите в сторону Moxy, может быть будет трудновато, но я использовал ее для реализации таких Flow.

Comment: Ну и соответственно будет это ViewPager или активити-контейнер, состоящая из одного FrameLayout, в котором будут хоститься фрагменты - решать вам